# Can someone explain to me the ending of Guilty Crown?

Tags: guilty-crown

I read some threads related to Shu case, for example that he took all the voids and illness of each people to save them but then Inori in some way she took them and die instead of Shu. And after that Shu becomes blind because Inori was like that before she dies?

I am not sure..

Comment: This is extremely late but I think giving this response is still needed as the other answer gave the implication that Inori is dead, which there is speculation that she is not. For more info, read this post, I know it's really long, but trust me, it changes your feelings regarding the ending. http://myanimelist.net/forum/?topicid=1408286

Answer (score 6, accepted):

During episode 22 after Shu defeats Gai and both he and Mana crystalize, Shu then uses both his original King power and Gai's power to absorb every single void and Apocalypse Virus remaining on the planet. After this action Shu becomes fully crystalized and has a vision of Inori offering him the Guilty Crown and Shu accepts. By this acceptance of the crown Shu and Inori switch places. A trade happens and Inori receives all of Shu's illness and he receives hers. ref([Guilty Crown Wiki](http://guiltycrown.wikia.com/wiki/Episode_22))

Answer (score 1):

In the end Inori gave Shu her soul, Shu and Inori became one. Inori wanted Shu to live on which is why she gave her soul to him even though they can never meet again. Inori was blind before she gave her soul to Shu which explains why Shu is blind at the last part of ep 22.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Just watched this anime and the ending, like everyone else had me confused and bothered. Seems vague but after reading several discussions on forums I think I can break it down and explain the reality I haven't seen anyone else come to:

To understand what happened you have to think like the writer, and what thematic point they're making. Thesis is the main message of the story, anti-thesis is the narrative tool to highlight thesis, using Protagonist and Antagonists to represent these ideas. Shu and Inori are thesis and Gai and Mana are anti-thesis.

Shu's battle is against the selfish, survival of the fittest "natural selection" of human nature represented by Gai and Mana--who only seek to reproduce themselves, also Doth who represents the natural drive of reproduction. Shu's selfless nature and Inoris innocence represent the opposition to this.

In the end Gai wanted to save Mana, Shu's sister, because he couldn't care less about anyone else and was willing to sacrifice all of humanity to be with her. Remember when Mana talked to Shu about Triton looking at her?  Triton liked her and still did to the end. In the end Gai went to Mana's traumatized body before the lost Christmas event to be with her to save Shu's sister but they both died. However, since Shu was absorbing all the voids he took Gai's void power, his king power. Eve represents the potential to create a new world. Shu could have created a new world but with Mana's body gone there was no person to house the EVE creation power, but Inori was the whole time created solely to house the EVE power. Inori was preserved genetically with her last tear  that dropped and crystallized as the flower Shu took hold of. Having that Shu basically had Inori's soul.

This is where people miss the point, Shu had the king's power and could create the new humanity but EVE was gone. Inori was still existing though and came to Shu. Shu used his Gai void power to Bring EVE out of Inori, since that's the only way he could be with her---he took the seat as king and made Inori INTO EVE--remember Inori was a copy of Mona, and had the EVE power to remake the world within her--Shu just needed Gai's power to bring it out of her.

Since he was able to bring Inori's latent EVE power out Inori offers Shu her cradle, which is red string representing her soul and he took it, basically finalizing the creation process, HOWEVER, Shu did not destroy the world and remake it like the antithesis (Gai and Mana) were planning. INSTEAD he took Inori's soul like Gai wanted to do with Mana, to be one and with her forever, and he gave the world life by not destroying it and ridding it of the void plague.

Shu was still alive but at the end he and Inori were 'in heaven" (or the crystal plane as they said) together forever, their souls and hearts one, just like how Gai and Mana planned.   As for Shu losing his sight--he rid void powers from the world, and his void power was connected with his eyes, since his eyes were what drew out the voids of others, so when he got rid of the powers his eyesight also went. I think it's coincidence that Inori couldn't see due to the crystal plague that had almost totally consumed her body.

So to conclude, Inori's body was gone, but she became EVE (a new "Eve") in the process and took over the role as the force that provide the power to re-create the world, and since Shu took the cradle, signifying his unity with her as king, they both lived in heaven together for eternity from then on. He didn't lose her at all, their souls were united (and she isn't just some distant memory. He's really with her there in the other world and she's very much alive). If Shu healed Inori he would've died having taken all the void plague and she would've lived without him, she chose to give him her power as Eve and offer as an alternative to be Eve and let them join in spirit, which let them be together and still (even though she's just a soul in 'heaven/crystal world') save the world from the void plague. The alternative was Shu saves himself but the void plague kills Inori. If either of them were selfish one would've lost the other.  It's such a heartbreakingly warm story and hits you in the feels to know they transcended any level of love if they both lived physically. Their love truly rules all and would last forever.

Answer (score 0):

I guess Inori gives her soul to Shu before she died as the red strings in the anime represent a person's soul.

Also, it's not correct that Shu and Inori will never be able to meet again. They can still meet at that place called as 'spirit lobby', the place where Shu talks to Jun.

Comment: Welcome to [anime.se], a Q&A site about anime & manga. I removed the statement regarding "the writer & season 2" because this site is not a discussion forum where anyone can state their own personal opinion freely unrelated to the question. Answers should be answering the question, *without distraction*. Also, consider taking a quick [tour] to understand how this site works.

Answer (score 0):

The red thread of 'Fate/Life' (same thing Yahiro's void can cut) that connects them was unexpectedly severed by Inori moving 'away' from Shu. In the beginning of the series we know that Inori offers the same threads to shu, the meaning of it not fully understood yet by that time. Now we know that this thread symbolizes her Fate, and her asking Shu to 'take it' is her invitation to Shu into her Fate. In the end of the series we see Inori doing the same thing, and Shu fully accepts it and decides to rest in eternity with Inori inside the crystal, taking all the remnants of Void/Apocalypse from the world and into eternal rest. However, Inori did not wanted Shu to die, so before the 'end of all' she lets go of Shu and moves 'away'. She chooses to die alone and let Shu live, leaving the whole world 'without all Voids, all Apocalypse, and without Inori' knowing she cannot be saved anyways (There is no way to save her but by Shu taking all the Apocalypse from her, of course that would result in Shu dying and she didn't want that).